# All texts goes to the top of the screen in Chat UI page

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

i have a Chat UI page where users can text each others,but the problem is for example when user X send a text it goes to the top and when user Y reply the text should be under the text that was send by user X but no it also goes to the top above the text that was send by user X,, dont know why it does that

here is my code

```
<StackLayout>

<ListView height="90%" margin-bottom="50" padding="5" #list [items]="chats$ | async">

    <ng-template let-item="item">

        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto" class="msg">

            <StackLayout [class]="filter(item.from)" orientation="horizontal" [horizontalAlignment]="align(item.from)">

                <Image [visibility]="showImage(item.from)" class="authorimg" stretch="aspectFill" height="30" width="30" verticalAlignment="top" src="~/images/k1.png" col="1"></Image>

                <Label [text]='item.message' class="msg_text" textWrap="true" verticalAlignment="top"></Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </GridLayout>

    </ng-template>

</ListView>



<StackLayout #chatbox height="10%">

    <GridLayout columns="*,auto" style="padding: 10">

        <TextField #textfield class="chatTextField" row="0" col="0" [(ngModel)]="message"></TextField>

        <Button #btn class="chatBtn" row="0" col="1" text="send" (tap)=chat(message)></Button>

    </GridLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: why not `.sort()` the array of messages by date/time?

Comment: this isnt a code writing service, you need to try to manage it yourself

Comment: your suggestion solved the issue cheers

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKE6L.jpg)
here is the screenshot
note:user X send  'HI' then user y replied 'Hey' and so on

Answer (score -1):

Your StackLayout css should be added with below code

```
<classname> {
    display: block;
}
```

When you give this there will be no overlapping of messages. And it would occupy the whole parent element's width.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of what is wrong in UI

Comment: The emulator screenshot